# Another kind of primality related to tessellations by polygons

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, discrete-geometry

You can define a number $p$ to be prime  by *"no tessellation of $p$ identical squares forms a convex figure"*. This suggests what I'll call a t-prime $p$, defined by "*no tessellation of $p$ identical equilateral triangles forms a convex figure*".

Are there infinitely many t-primes?

I have thought about a "scaffold" in order to prove this analogously to the corresponding assertion for (regular) primes.

Comment: For some body who don’t know what tessellation is, it means arrangement.. I didn’t knew, I did google just now :P

Comment: For squares, you have to exclude the trivial case of a 1xp rectangle formed by these squares. Similarly, you need to put some similar restriction on the convex figures formed by triangles.

Comment: These convex regions are either hexagons, pentagons, parallelograms or trapezoids or equilateral triangles. Have you tried expressing the area of such a figure as a multiple of the area of the base triangle for each case? Likely you'll find restrictions on the associated areas and maybe those are enough to find the answer (whatever it is).

Comment: Triangles <-> triangular numbers, (nontrivial) parallelograms <-> multiples of 4, trapezoids <-> differences of two triangular numbers.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat I think you made an error with parallelograms - 2 equilateral triangles stuck on each other form a parallelogram.

Comment: I think representability by quadratic forms applies here: Take a large triangle and subtract three small triangles to get a representation of many numbers less than the number of unit triangles in the large triangle.  I suspect all sufficiently large numbers "look like" irregular hexagons this way.  This would mean a no answer to your question.  Gerhard "Even Embedded In Two Ways" Paseman, 2020.04.13.

Comment: @user44191 I followed Wojowu's comment which I interpreted as "exclude lines of triangles"

Comment: @OlivierBégassat I can still get 18, or twice any composite number, with that restriction on parallelograms.

Comment: How about convex tesselations by $1\times2$ rectangles? (excluding trivial cases)

Comment: @GerryMyerson. 3 is composite as 2 vertical rectangles with a horizontal on top show; then adding more horizontals on top show all larger numbers to be composite too - unless you have some way of defining trivial arrangements that excludes those. But it would be really nice if there were some non trivial way of rescuing this question... I thought about Penrose tilings, but that didn't give anything interesting as far I could see...

Answer (score 1):

I believe the only t-primes are $1,2,3$ and $5$. OP hasn't clarified what kind of "trivial" configurations they wish to exclude, but hopefully the ones below are nontrivial enough.

Here is a visual proof of the fact any number $n\geq 7$ is not t-prime. The idea is to first give constructions of convex figures consisting of $6k+1$ triangles (first row below) and then appending moe triangles to cover other residue classes mod $6$ (second row). Excuse my crude drawings.

[image]